# ActiveAndroid custom primary key for Create and Update Record

Tags: activeandroid

This is my Model, where Im maintaining id myself.

Table(name = "Master")
public class Master extends Model {

```
@Column(name = "masterId")
public int id;

@Column(name = "name")
public String name;

@Column(name = "description")
public String description;
```

}

How to set my custom column as primary, which supports create and update.

Answer (score 2):

user id in @table annotation to define your custom id

```
@Table(name = "Items", id = "_id")
public class Master extends Model {

    @Column(name = "masterId")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String description;

}
```